# $f$ be a ring automorphism on $R[x]$ such that $f(u)=u , \forall u \in R$ , then is it true that $f(x)=ax+b $ for some $a,b \in R$?

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring and $f:R[x] \to R[x]$ be a ring automorphism such that $f(u)=u , \forall u \in R$ , then is it true that $f(x)=ax+b $ for some $a,b \in R$ ?

Comment: why the downvote ? is it because I haven't give my thoughts ? because I am totally stuck !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $R$ is an integral domain, it is easy to see $f(x)=ax+b$, with $a\in R^\times, b\in R$.

Indeed,since $f$ is surjective, $x$ must be attained, i.e. there exists a polynomial $p$ such that $f\bigl(p(x)\bigr)=x.\,$ As $R$ is an integral domain, $\deg(f\bigl(p(x)\bigr)=\deg f(x)\cdot \deg p(x)$, hence
$$ \deg f(x)=\deg p(x)=1. $$
So $f(x)=ax+b,\enspace p(x)=cx+d\enspace (a,b,c,d \in R)$. Also the coefficient of $x$ is $ac$, hence $a, c$ are units.

Conversely, if $f(x)=ax+b,\enspace a\in R^\times$, it's easy to check that $f^{-1}(x)=a^{-1}(x-b)$.

**If $\boldsymbol R$ is not an integral domain,** this is no more true: take $R=\mathbf Z/4 \mathbf Z$. Then setting $f(x)=2x^2+x+1$, we get an automorphism, since in this ring: $$(2x^2+x+1)^2=x.$$

Comment: It is an $R$-automorphism, since I define only the image of $x$.

Comment: By definition, an $R$-algebra homomorphism leaves the elements of $R$. That's why it is enough to define the image of $x$: onece you know the image of the generator of the algebra, you can compute the image of any element.